# how to upload a single file to a specific path on GitHub

Tags: git, github, cron, centos

Well i need generate auto backup to my private GitHub account.
My idea is generate a backup every X time and after generate sql script, upload this to my private repo in github.

Example:

**Cron:**

```
* * * * * /backup-generator-for-github.sh
```

**backup-generator-for-github.sh:**

```
# mysqldump --databases MyPersonalDatabase > dump.sql    
# git upload /dump.sql --path github.com/xx/privateRepo/folder/dump.sql --username xxxx --password xxxxxx
```

My OS is Centos 7

Thanks

Comment: Git is not really a good solution to store database backups.

Comment: No, but this backup is a "structure" of database, so, right niw i editing the database structure and i nned update structure in the private repo

Comment: github is not for general file storage. This really isn't the right way to do this. If this dump is something you are using git to version control that's (probably horrible) but a different question but it doesn't look like that's what is going on here. Why are you trying to use github for this?

Comment: Well, every X time i update my database structure(personal project) and, i want store all system on github like to "php script, sql scripts, etc".. no need store "inserts/data", only need auto update the structure in a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you should create the .sql file in a folder that is a git repository. The script would then add, commit, and push the updated database file. Something like this:

```
mysqldump --databases MyPersonalDatabase > dump.sql
git add dump.sql
git commit -m "Automatic database backup"
git push
```

If there's also some other activity on the repo, the script would first have to pull. Then you would have to handle merge conflicts etc...